# Validating User defined variables

Tags: jmeter

I have several user defined variables set via properties i would like to validate.

I can use a jsr223 sampler to validate these but i dont want to duplicate all the names which are already set in the user defined variables.

Is there some programatic way to get hold of the declared user defined variables, possibly via the sampler or context variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which holds all the JMeter Variables (including the ones you set via [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) class).

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on `vars` and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

---

However this way you will get all the JMeter Variables including [pre-defined ones](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)

If you want to validate only the variables you have defined in the User Defined Variables configuration element you can play a little trick with the [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass


def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField('test')

test.setAccessible(true)

def testPlanTree = test.get(engine)

SearchByClass<Arguments> udvSearch = new SearchByClass<>(Arguments.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(udvSearch)
Collection<Arguments> udv = udvSearch.getSearchResults()

udv.each { arguments ->
    0.upto(arguments.size() - 1, { rowNum ->
        def arg = arguments.getArgument(rowNum)
        log.info('Variable name = ' + arg.getName() + ', variable value = ' + arg.getValue())
    })
}
```

Comment: Brilliant that is just what i was after